# Chroma key shader for WebCamTexture in Unity3D

Tags: c#, image-processing, unity-game-engine, shader, chromakey

How can I make chroma key attribute to eleminate a color from WebCamTexture. WebCamTexture provides very limited control on texture.

Comment: Please expand upon your post - What are you trying to do at a high level? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using Aforge but now in unity3d. I can detect color and highlight those but I want to eliminate that color just as we do with chroma key technique. later I ll apply this trick in Unity3D.

Comment: I want to make a software that can capture realtime video using webcam and remove chroma key based on user selected color.

Comment: Here http://u3d.as/6A4 you've got a shader I made for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example shader that could be used: http://pastebin.com/rxJak3jB

Answer (score 0):

Check out the transparency shaders that come with Unity [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/shader-TransparentFamily.html). You simply need to update the alpha channel mask of your texture with the areas of the texture you want made transparent.